# Table shows when I go to edit an object, but not when I want to create a new one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table that shows fields. These show fine when it calls an existing object. I want to use this table to add new objects. It won't show the table when the object is null.

Here's the table code.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>SKU</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="sub in active.sub">
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="sub.sku" name="sku" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="sub.name" name="name" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input money type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sub.sale" name="sale" min="1" max="1000000" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="sub.stock" name="stock" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way of making it show the table when the object is null? Here's what it looks like.

[image: Screenshot of webpage]

Comment: Which object you are checking for null? Please specify the name from your sample code.

Comment: Which object is immaterial. The object doesn't exist at that point. What I want is for the table to show when the values are null so I can create a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>SKU</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="sub in active.sub" ng-init="active.sub=[{
 'sku':' ',
 'name':' ',
  'sale':' ',
  'stock':' '
}]">
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="sub.sku" name="sku" /></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="sub.name" name="name" /></td>
                        <td><input money type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sub.sale" name="sale" min="1" max="1000000"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="sub.stock" name="stock" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Set `ng-init="active.sub=[{sku:"",name"",sale:"",stock:" " }]` inside tr tag.

Or set one default array as $scope.active.sub=[{sku:" ",name" ",sale:" ",stock:" " }] and on getting data from a service, push the data into this array.

I mightnot be syntactically right but Idea is to have an empty value for each variable in json in the beginning.

Edit:
Check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4hta18jy/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-repeat create rows based on the length of the array on which you have put ng-repeat. And if the value of object is null means length is 0 than it will not create any row. so if u want a row in case of null you can initialize the array with a object so it can create a row.

<table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>SKU</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="sub in active.sub"  ng-init="active.sub == null ? active.sub=[{
 'sku':' ',
 'name':' ',
  'sale':' ',
  'stock':' '
}] : ''">
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="sub.sku" name="sku" /></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="sub.name" name="name" /></td>
                        <td><input money type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sub.sale" name="sale" min="1" max="1000000"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="sub.stock" name="stock" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

It will assign a object to the array active.sub if it is null.